# Draft.js initial text with design

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

Im using Draft.js with React. The user can add text with style and save it to the database.
I want the user also to be able to edit, and so I use:

```
EditorState.createWithContent(ContentState.createFromText(text))
```

to initial the editor with the text, but the design is not shown (Bold, insert with a link, underline, and so on..)
How can I upload an initial text with its design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store the raw state wich contains all formatings and entities.

To get the raw state use the following code:

```js
    const content = editorState.getCurrentContent();
    const contentToDb= convertToRaw(content);
```

To restore the raw state:

```js
    const rawContent = convertFromRaw(contentFromDb);
    const state = EditorState.createWithContent(rawContent);
    setEditorState(state);
```